# JQuery - page does not reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After a form is submitted via `ajax`, I want to reload the updated page with this jquery:

```
<p align="left"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-sample btn-md reset send" id="send" name="commit"><b>Save</b></button>

$('.send').click(function(){
    location.reload(true);
});
```

However it doesn't do the reload, unless I click on `F5` manually.

Comment: Why are you using ajax if you reload the page afterwards anyway? ... any errors you get in the console?

Comment: Are you submit form, that form methods is GET or POST ?

Comment: I submit via POST and there are no errors given

Comment: Why you don't update the page with the result you get from ajax call?

Comment: It should work, what's the browser you are using?

Comment: Sure your $('.send') is set after your html code is loaded ? Try jQuery(document).on('click','.send',function(){ ... } wich will make it live

Comment: @PierreGranger, it is set after html but still doesn't do the refresh.

Comment: Refreshing the page kinda takes away the point of using ajax.

Comment: I was able to refresh on `$ajax success:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`$.post()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) jQuery Method to post form data easily as well as reload the page.

```
$.post( "test.php", 
    { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
    function() {window.location.reload(); } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that unless you return `false` in the click event handler, the form will be submitted by `<button type="submit" />` and you won't be able to see the result of any ajax call due to the page being reloaded

Comment: This should probably be a comment.